# jpa named and criteria query fail when running on webserver (wildfly) in spring mvc 4 webapplication with java configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have the following simple spring mvc 4 application with JPA 2.0 using java config

```
package com.somecompany.class;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Import({JPAConfig.class, BeanConfig.class})
@ComponentScan("com.*")
public class AppConfig {

public InternalResourceViewResolver setupInternalResourceViewResolver() {

    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return resolver;
}

}
```

The AppConfig.java class contains the application configuration logic

```
package com.somecompany.class;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver;
import org.springframework.instrument.classloading.LoadTimeWeaver;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.somecompany.model.*")
public class JPAConfig {

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {

    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(getEntityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean containerEntityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    containerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
    containerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("pmd-web");
    LoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver = new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver();
    containerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setLoadTimeWeaver(loadTimeWeaver);
    return containerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/somedatabase");
    dataSource.setUsername("someuser");
    dataSource.setPassword("somepassword");
    return dataSource;
}

}
```

The JPAConfig.java contains the JPA configuration details

```
package com.somecompany.class;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.Dynamic; 

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    webApplicationContext.register(AppConfig.class);
    webApplicationContext.setServletContext(servletContext);
    webApplicationContext.refresh();
    Dynamic dynamic = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(webApplicationContext));
    dynamic.addMapping("/");
    dynamic.setLoadOnStartup(1);
}

}
```

WebAppInitializer.java contains the logic for initializing the web app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="pmd-web">
    <description>project metrics dashboard</description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

persistence.xml is as above.

```
package com.somecompany.Controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.somecompany.VO.LoginVO;
import com.somecompany.loginService.LoginService;

@RestController
public class LoginController {

@Autowired
LoginService loginService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<LoginVO> authenticateUser(@RequestBody LoginVO loginVO) {
    loginVO = loginService.authenticateUser(loginVO);
    if (loginVO.getStatus()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<LoginVO>(loginVO, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<LoginVO>(loginVO, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }

}

}
```

The Restful controller class is as above

```
package com.somecompany.loginService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import somecompany.VO.LoginVO;
import somecompany.mapper.LoginMapper;
import somecompany.model.PmdUser;
import com.somecompany.LoginDAO;

@Service
public class LoginService {

@Autowired
LoginDAO loginDAO;

@Autowired
LoginMapper loginMapper;

@Transactional
public LoginVO authenticateUser(LoginVO loginVO) {

    PmdUser pmdUser = loginMapper.getpmdUserFromLoginVO(loginVO);
    LoginVO loginVOFromDB = loginDAO.authenticateUser(pmdUser);

    if (loginVO.getUserName().equalsIgnoreCase(loginVOFromDB.getUserName())) {
        loginVO.setStatus(true);
    }
    return loginVO;
}

}
```

The service class is as above

```
package com.somecompany.loginDAO;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.somecompany.VO.LoginVO;
import com.somecompany.baseDAO.BaseDao;
import com.somecompany.mapper.LoginMapper;
import com.somecompany.model.PmdUser;
```

@Repository
public class LoginDAO extends BaseDao {

```
@Autowired
LoginMapper loginMapper;


public LoginVO authenticateUser(PmdUser pmdUser) {

    PmdUser user = null;
    LoginVO loginVO = null;
    List<PmdUser> pmdUsers = findByNamedQuery("findByUsername", pmdUser.getUserName());
    if (pmdUsers.size() > 0) {
        user = pmdUsers.get(0);
        loginVO = loginMapper.getLoginVOFromPmdUser(user);
    }
    return loginVO;
}
}
```

The loginDAO.java class is as above

```
package com.somecompany.baseDAO;

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceException;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion;
import org.hibernate.criterion.ProjectionList;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Projections;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public abstract class BaseDao<E, K> {

/** The entity manager. */
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "pmd-web")
protected EntityManager entityManager;

/**
 * Gets the entity manager.
 *
 * @return the entity manager
 */
public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}

/** The entity class. */
protected Class<E> entityClass;

/**
 * Instantiates a new base DAO.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public BaseDao() {
    ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    this.entityClass = (Class<E>) genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}

public List<E> findByNamedQuery(final String name, Object... params) {
    javax.persistence.Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(name);

    for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        query.setParameter(i + 1, params[i]);
    }

    final List<E> result = (List<E>) query.getResultList();
    return result;
}
}
```

On deploying the application war and execution the REST service i get the exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No query defined for that name [findByUsername]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.buildQueryFromName(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:788) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:767) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:294) [spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.createNamedQuery(Unknown Source)
at com.somecompany.baseDAO.BaseDao.findByNamedQuery(BaseDao.java:184) [classes:]
at com.somecompany.loginDAO.LoginDAO.authenticateUser(LoginDAO.java:26) [classes:]
at com.somecompany.loginDAO.LoginDAO$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1909bedd.invoke(<generated>) [classes:]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:651) [spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at com.somecompany.loginDAO.LoginDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$45d26c87.authenticateUser(<generated>) [classes:]
at com.somecompany.loginService.LoginService.authenticateUser(LoginService.java:25) [classes:]
at com.somecompany.loginService.LoginService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3de2163d.invoke(<generated>) [classes:]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) [spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) [spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) [spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) [spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at com.somecompany.loginService.LoginService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$912637e7.authenticateUser(<generated>) [classes:]
at com.somecompany.loginController.LoginController.authenticateUser(LoginController.java:22) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
... 30 more
```

But i have the named query on the entity as below

```
package com.somecompany.model;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Entity
@Table(name = "pmd_user", catalog = "pmd", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "CUSTOMER_ID", "USER_NAME" }),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "EMAIL_ADDRESS") })
@Component
@NamedQuery(name="findByUsername", query="SELECT u FROM PmdUser u WHERE u.userName = ?1")
public class PmdUser implements java.io.Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Long userId;
private PmdCustomer pmdCustomer;
private String userName;
private String emailAddress;
private Long phone;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String password;
private Boolean passwordChangeRequired;
private Date lastPasswordChange;
private Long challengeQuestionId;
private String challengeAnswer;
private Boolean deactivated;
private Boolean deleted;
private Boolean isPreview;
private Boolean receiveEmail;
private Boolean isGuest;
private Boolean newsletter;
private String emailFormat;
private Date dateOfLastLogon;
private Long visits;
private String note;
private Long createdIp;
private Long updatedIp;
private Date dateCreated;
private Date dateUpdated;
private Long createdBy;
private Long updatedBy;
private List<PmdUserRole> pmdUserRoles = new ArrayList<PmdUserRole>(0);

public PmdUser() {
}

public PmdUser(String userName, String emailAddress) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
}

public PmdUser(PmdCustomer pmdCustomer, String userName, String emailAddress, Long phone, String firstName,
        String lastName, String password, Boolean passwordChangeRequired, Date lastPasswordChange,
        Long challengeQuestionId, String challengeAnswer, Boolean deactivated, Boolean deleted, Boolean isPreview,
        Boolean receiveEmail, Boolean isGuest, Boolean newsletter, String emailFormat, Date dateOfLastLogon,
        Long visits, String note, Long createdIp, Long updatedIp, Date dateCreated, Date dateUpdated,
        Long createdBy, Long updatedBy, List<PmdUserRole> pmdUserRoles) {
    this.pmdCustomer = pmdCustomer;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.password = password;
    this.passwordChangeRequired = passwordChangeRequired;
    this.lastPasswordChange = lastPasswordChange;
    this.challengeQuestionId = challengeQuestionId;
    this.challengeAnswer = challengeAnswer;
    this.deactivated = deactivated;
    this.deleted = deleted;
    this.isPreview = isPreview;
    this.receiveEmail = receiveEmail;
    this.isGuest = isGuest;
    this.newsletter = newsletter;
    this.emailFormat = emailFormat;
    this.dateOfLastLogon = dateOfLastLogon;
    this.visits = visits;
    this.note = note;
    this.createdIp = createdIp;
    this.updatedIp = updatedIp;
    this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    this.dateUpdated = dateUpdated;
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
    this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
    this.pmdUserRoles = pmdUserRoles;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

@Column(name = "USER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Long getUserId() {
    return this.userId;
}

public void setUserId(Long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
public PmdCustomer getPmdCustomer() {
    return this.pmdCustomer;
}

public void setPmdCustomer(PmdCustomer pmdCustomer) {
    this.pmdCustomer = pmdCustomer;
}

@Column(name = "USER_NAME", nullable = false, length = 32)
public String getUserName() {
    return this.userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

@Column(name = "EMAIL_ADDRESS", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 128)
public String getEmailAddress() {
    return this.emailAddress;
}

public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
    this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
}

@Column(name = "PHONE")
public Long getPhone() {
    return this.phone;
}

public void setPhone(Long phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

@Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", length = 32)
public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

@Column(name = "LAST_NAME", length = 32)
public String getLastName() {
    return this.lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Column(name = "PASSWORD", length = 128)
public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Column(name = "PASSWORD_CHANGE_REQUIRED")
public Boolean getPasswordChangeRequired() {
    return this.passwordChangeRequired;
}

public void setPasswordChangeRequired(Boolean passwordChangeRequired) {
    this.passwordChangeRequired = passwordChangeRequired;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE", length = 19)
public Date getLastPasswordChange() {
    return this.lastPasswordChange;
}

public void setLastPasswordChange(Date lastPasswordChange) {
    this.lastPasswordChange = lastPasswordChange;
}

@Column(name = "CHALLENGE_QUESTION_ID")
public Long getChallengeQuestionId() {
    return this.challengeQuestionId;
}

public void setChallengeQuestionId(Long challengeQuestionId) {
    this.challengeQuestionId = challengeQuestionId;
}

@Column(name = "CHALLENGE_ANSWER", length = 128)
public String getChallengeAnswer() {
    return this.challengeAnswer;
}

public void setChallengeAnswer(String challengeAnswer) {
    this.challengeAnswer = challengeAnswer;
}

@Column(name = "DEACTIVATED")
public Boolean getDeactivated() {
    return this.deactivated;
}

public void setDeactivated(Boolean deactivated) {
    this.deactivated = deactivated;
}

@Column(name = "DELETED")
public Boolean getDeleted() {
    return this.deleted;
}

public void setDeleted(Boolean deleted) {
    this.deleted = deleted;
}

@Column(name = "IS_PREVIEW")
public Boolean getIsPreview() {
    return this.isPreview;
}

public void setIsPreview(Boolean isPreview) {
    this.isPreview = isPreview;
}

@Column(name = "RECEIVE_EMAIL")
public Boolean getReceiveEmail() {
    return this.receiveEmail;
}

public void setReceiveEmail(Boolean receiveEmail) {
    this.receiveEmail = receiveEmail;
}

@Column(name = "IS_GUEST")
public Boolean getIsGuest() {
    return this.isGuest;
}

public void setIsGuest(Boolean isGuest) {
    this.isGuest = isGuest;
}

@Column(name = "NEWSLETTER")
public Boolean getNewsletter() {
    return this.newsletter;
}

public void setNewsletter(Boolean newsletter) {
    this.newsletter = newsletter;
}

@Column(name = "EMAIL_FORMAT", length = 4)
public String getEmailFormat() {
    return this.emailFormat;
}

public void setEmailFormat(String emailFormat) {
    this.emailFormat = emailFormat;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "DATE_OF_LAST_LOGON", length = 19)
public Date getDateOfLastLogon() {
    return this.dateOfLastLogon;
}

public void setDateOfLastLogon(Date dateOfLastLogon) {
    this.dateOfLastLogon = dateOfLastLogon;
}

@Column(name = "VISITS")
public Long getVisits() {
    return this.visits;
}

public void setVisits(Long visits) {
    this.visits = visits;
}

@Column(name = "NOTE", length = 65535)
public String getNote() {
    return this.note;
}

public void setNote(String note) {
    this.note = note;
}

@Column(name = "CREATED_IP")
public Long getCreatedIp() {
    return this.createdIp;
}

public void setCreatedIp(Long createdIp) {
    this.createdIp = createdIp;
}

@Column(name = "UPDATED_IP")
public Long getUpdatedIp() {
    return this.updatedIp;
}

public void setUpdatedIp(Long updatedIp) {
    this.updatedIp = updatedIp;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "DATE_CREATED", length = 19)
public Date getDateCreated() {
    return this.dateCreated;
}

public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
    this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "DATE_UPDATED", length = 19)
public Date getDateUpdated() {
    return this.dateUpdated;
}

public void setDateUpdated(Date dateUpdated) {
    this.dateUpdated = dateUpdated;
}

@Column(name = "CREATED_BY")
public Long getCreatedBy() {
    return this.createdBy;
}

public void setCreatedBy(Long createdBy) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
}

@Column(name = "UPDATED_BY")
public Long getUpdatedBy() {
    return this.updatedBy;
}

public void setUpdatedBy(Long updatedBy) {
    this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pmdUser")
public List<PmdUserRole> getPmdUserRoles() {
    return this.pmdUserRoles;
}

public void setPmdUserRoles(List<PmdUserRole> pmdUserRoles) {
    this.pmdUserRoles = pmdUserRoles;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "PmdUser [userId=" + userId + ", userName=" + userName + ", emailAddress=" + emailAddress
            + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + "]";
}
}
```

I suspect this is due to an integration issue with spring and JPA as the same query works fine in a unit test.

Has anybody faced this issue before ? or Is my JPA configuration not complete ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the class deceleration in the Persistence.xml file previously the deceleration was as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="pmd-web">
    <description>project metrics dashboard</description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

and had to change it to have the class declarations

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="pmd-web">
    <class>com.somecompany.model.PmdCustomer</class>
    <class>com.somecompany.model.CustomerModule</class>
    <class>com.somecompany.model.Modules</class>
    <class>com.somecompany.model.Project</class>
    <class>com.somecompany.model.ProjectRelease</class>
    <class>com.somecompany.model.ProjectSprint</class>
    <class>com.somecompany.model.Role</class>
    <class>com.somecompany.model.User</class>
    <class>com.somecompany.model.UserRole</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to your persistence xml location :

```
containerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath:...");
```

Refer to your entities either from persistence xml **OR**

```
containerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.somecomany.model");
```

And you are configuring repositories from the wrong location, change :

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.somecompany.model.*")
```

to  :

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.somecompany")
```

Comment: Tried after changing the location of basePackages but still facing the same exception.

Comment: @praveen you are not refering to your persistence.xml anywhere, so your models aren't picked up

Comment: am not sure where to refer the persistence.xml ? Do you have any idea about it ?

Comment: @praveen i  edited the answer , you need to refer your entities either on the persitence context or by setting a package to scan.

Comment: tried both but still facing the same issue not sure why? will update the JPAConfig class with your suggestions.